# Google Charts - Overlays: "getChartLayoutInterface is not a function" for elevation line chart drawn within Google Maps InfoWindow

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-visualization, infowindow

I'm trying to add a custom overlay to an elevation line chart that's displayed within a Maps InfoWindow. I've been working off of [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/overlays#positioning-overlaysrelative-to-data) without any luck. Hoping someone can help - I've been banging my head against a wall all day.

Here's my code:

```
       chartPopUp.setContent(
       '<div id="elevationChart"></div> <div class="overlay-marker"><img src="https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/images/zombie_150.png" height="50"></div>'
       );

        displayPathElevation(path, elevator, map);

        function displayPathElevation(path, elevator, map) {

            // Create a PathElevationRequest object using this array.
            // Initiate the path request.
            elevator.getElevationAlongPath({
                'path': path,
                'samples': 30,
                }, plotElevation);
        }

        function plotElevation(elevations, status) {
            if (status !== 'OK') {
                chartDiv.innerHTML = 'Cannot show elevation: request failed because ' +
                status;
                return;
            }

           // Create a new chart in the elevationChart DIV.
           // Extract the data from which to populate the chart.

            var arr = [];
            arr.push(['Distance', 'Elevation'])
            for (var i = 0; i < elevations.length; i++) {
                arr.push(['', elevations[i].elevation]);
            }

            var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr);
            placeMarkerData = data;

            var options = {
                            height: 400,
                            width: 600,
                            legend: 'none',
                            title: 'ELEVATION (m)',
                            colors: ['#252328'],
                            pointSize: 5,
                            tooltip: true,
                            curveType: 'function',
                            vAxis: {
                                minValue: '0',
                                maxValue: 100,
                                viewWindow: {
                                    min: 0,
                                    max: 100 
                                },
                            },
                        };
            elevationChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('elevationChart'));
            elevationChart.draw(data, options);
            placeMarker(elevationChart);

        }

        function placeMarker(dataTable) {
            cli = this.getChartLayoutInterface();
            var chartArea = cli.getChartAreaBoundingBox();
            document.querySelector('.overlay-marker').style.top = Math.floor(cli.getYLocation(dataTable.getValue(dataTable.length - 1, 1))) + "px";
            document.querySelector('.overlay-marker').style.left = Math.floor(cli.getXLocation(1)) - 10 + "px";
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the `placeMarker` function with...

```
    function placeMarker(chart, dataTable) {
        cli = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
        var chartArea = cli.getChartAreaBoundingBox();
        document.querySelector('.overlay-marker').style.top = Math.floor(cli.getYLocation(dataTable.getValue(dataTable.length - 1, 1))) + "px";
        document.querySelector('.overlay-marker').style.left = Math.floor(cli.getXLocation(1)) - 10 + "px";
    };
```